# How do i make a headerwith a paragraph while being aligned to a picture?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

So what I want to do is a Paragraph on the side of an image, that I already made :

[image]

But with another line with a paragraph:

[image]

But instead of being like how it is shown on the picture, it's like that:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Here is the HTML:

```
<center>
  <h1 style="color:white;">
  <img align="middle" src="OOOgamelibrary.png">Game Library</h1>
  <p style="color:white;">PlaceHolder</p>
</center>
```

Comment: you just want put the image a side in the right, and the two paragraphs in left?

Comment: `<center>` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used. I'm surprised they're still teaching this stuff.

Comment: Not 2 paragraphs, a header and a paragraph, but yes.

Comment: @Paulie_D it's supposed to be a 1995 styled website so, i use old methods.

Comment: So use modern techniques, and elements that still exist in the spec, to make it *look* like a 1995 website.

Comment: Please beware of the use of style inside the elements, you must avoid do this too

Comment: I made a adjust in my answer to include the h2, pls check if fit to you

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
        padding: 50px;
    }
    
    .container {
        padding: 20px 40px 40px;
        max-width: 640px;
        display: flex;
    
    
    }
    
    .image {
            margin: 20px 30px 0 0;
            width: 200px;
            object-fit: contain;
            align-self: flex-start;
        }
    
    .text {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <img class=" image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/d941d9/fff.png&text=dummy+image">
        <div class=" text">
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.

```css
.wrapper {
display: flex;
}

img{
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x80">
<div class="paragrapg">
<h3>This is heading</h3>
<p>This is the paragraph</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to do that, you can use Flexbox or Grid CSS too, and here is just one way, the principle is of using "float" In this way is needed a bit more code to adjust, see here

```css
#bg_game{ max-width:350px; height:130px; background:#111;  overflow:hidden;}
#bg_game figure{ margin:0px; width:30%; float:left; height:100%;  overflow:hidden; display:block; padding:20px;}
#bg_game img{ max-width:100%; height:auto;}
#bg_game div{float:left;  height:100%; padding-left:10px; overflow:hidden; max-width:70%;   color:#fff;}
#bg_game h2{ margin-top:25px;}
#bg_game p{ margin-top:-5px;}
```

```html
<div id='bg_game'>
<figure>
<img src="https://cake.imgix.net/m/88ZhML3x76yX_1546370106139.png">
</figure>
<div>
<h2>Game Library</h2> 
<p>PlaceHolder</p>
</div>
</div>
```